# Can not find sink inputs when using pacmd

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio

I am trying to redirect the sound produced by laptop to a bluetooth speaker. I know how to redirect the sound of sink inputs to different sinks. However, when I am playing music, sound is coming from my laptop but when I use the command

```
$ pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

I get this in response

```
0 sink input(s) available.
```

I have no idea why I am getting this response. I have tested with multiple applications but I continue to receive this. Does anyone have ideas where I can look into this to investigate this further?

Comment: When you are playing music, do you see the application in `pavucontrol`? Does it show up with `pacmd list-clients`? Have you tried another application like `mplayer`?

Comment: I don't see any either. it's probably normal. If you don't get a good answer here, try asking on the PA list: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/pulseaudio-discuss .

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me if anyone is facing the same issue as of this year.

```
pulseaudio --start -D
```

Comment: What does that command do?  How does it solve the problem? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to redirect the sound produced by laptop to a bluetooth speaker.

You mean as in "all applications should use the bluetooth speaker instead of the laptop speaker", or "in addition to the laptop speaker, the sound should come out of the bluetooth speaker", or "I want to keep using the laptop speaker, but when I have the bluetooth speaker connected, I want to use the bluetooth speaker"? Or something else?

> When I use the command `pacmd list-sink-inputs` I get this in response `0 sink input(s) available.`

That means no sound applications are currently using any sinks, from the pulseaudio connection you get via commandline. So do you have an application running that actually produces sounds? Can you see it producing sound with `pavucontrol`?

> I know how to redirect the sound of sink inputs to different sinks.

That might not be the answer to your problem, depending on what variant you want (see above).